# Bootstrap Infinite Loop Carousel 4 Slides - Javascript Mod Needed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using the following boostrap snippet code found here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop

The javascript that this carousel uses to display 3 slides at a time is:

```
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 40000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {

      next.next().children(':first-    child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');

  }
  else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-Child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  }
});
</script>
```

I was trying to modify this java to apply the ".rightest" class to the 4th or 5th slide instead of the 3rd but everything I tried didn't work. I am really not well versed in javascript, I tried checking the suggestions found in the comments from that link above but they do not work, you cannot accomplish more than 3 slides without changing that javascript and changing where that class is assigned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There appears to be some typos in your code snippet.  For instance the space (or tab) between ':first-    child' on line 15 and ':first-Child' (capitalization) on line 18, try fixing these sorts of syntax problems first.

Comment: Please be clear about what you are asking for... What is your actual question? What is your intended result? What have you already tried?

Comment: That was a code formatting error when I created the post.

Comment: My intended result is instead of the java assigning the class rightest to teh 3rd item it assigns it to the 4th or possibly even the 5th.